# Entity Framework Core configurations with existing database

Tags: entity-framework-core, database-migration

In one of my projects, I am using an existing SQL Server database. All the database scripts are managed using DBUp and SQL script migrations.

In my application, I am using Entity Framework Core to communicate with this database. When I configure my entities in EF configurations, should I still define functions like `IsRequired()`, `HasMaxLenth()` etc.?

I am not using these EF configurations to generate migration scripts; all the migration is outside of EF. I am just using these configurations to communicate with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I configure my Entities in EF configurations, should I still define functions like IsRequired(), HasMaxLenth() etc.?

Other than table and column name mapping and data type mapping, it's not required, but additional model metadata might be used by front-end components for validation.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. What about HasColumnName? I noticed that even though the Property name and the Database Column name are same, the Property doesn't map unless I define HasColunName..... But if I keep the HasMaxLength or IsRequired (or any other function in the configuration) the mapping works fine....

Comment: For example, currently in one of my configurations, I have "builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();", If I completely remove this code from the configuration, my expectation is because the Property name and the column name are same, it would automatically map.... but it doesn't and I get error when saving the entity.... so either I need to have "builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();" or builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name");" present in the code for it to work

Comment: Yes.  Mapping the column names and data types is required for correct and optimal query generation.  HasMaxLength is part of the data type.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, you should keep them. Many of these configurations are used throughout EF to make decisions at runtime. For example, some queries can be further optimized if EF knows that a column is never NULL, the max length is used to configure the SQL parameters it sends to the database, and unique constraints are used to sort SQL statements during SaveChanges.

While a few things like constraint names, non-unique indexes, index filters, and sequences aren't currently used at runtime, it's hard to know which ones EF will and won't use, so it's best just to keep them all.

And sometimes, database features like always encrypted on SQL Server, will fail entirely if the mappings aren't precise.